# Dependency Diagrams in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a VS 2010 solution with 17 projects in it. I want to make a dependency diagram which shows dependencies between the projects.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at my latest program at http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/visual-studio-solution-dependency-visualizer/